# Removing unexpected space in :before :after pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I recently had a problem when I was adding SVGs to :before and after pseudo elements to get curved sections on a page.

```
.div:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: url(svg/curve-down-bottom.svg);
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The method worked great apart from that there was additional space below the SVG within the pseudo element, as shown below:

[image: Unwanted space below svg in pseudo element]

I tried many methods to fix this, but see my answer below for the one that worked!

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: you need to add a complete html/css code and use absolute path of your SVG. we cannot help you in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding line-height: 0; fixed the issue, as below:

```
.div:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: url(svg/curve-down-bottom.svg);
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

A you can see here:

[image: pseudo element without additional space]

As others have commented you could also add **display: block;**. This has worked with similar issues in the past where images have space below, however with this specific issue **line-height:0;** provided the desired result.

```
.div:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: url(svg/curve-down-bottom.svg);
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Using `display: block` would be a better solution.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I tried everything, including `display:block` and it didn't work

Comment: @PaulLeBeau. Thanks for the suggestion. As mentioned, the example CSS I provided was the solution that worked for me. I've added your suggestion of display: block as despite it not being the solution in this case, it has worked with certain similar issues in the past. Thanks!